# number of quantity to is not working in Opencart

Tags: php, jquery, opencart

I added to increase quantity using jquery code

```
$(".quantity-adder .add-action").click(function () {
     if ($(this).hasClass('add-up')) {
         var text = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("[name=quantity]", '.quantity-adder')
         text.val(parseInt(text.val()) + 1);
     } else {
         var text = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("[name=quantity]", '.quantity-adder')
         if (parseInt(text.val()) > 1) {
             text.val(parseInt(text.val()) - 1);
         }
     }
});
```

when i add this code in product page, and clicking the plus button, quantity increases and when clicked on add to cart its working fine

http://itracktraining.com/optest/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=40

but same thing is not working in homepage featured one

http://itracktraining.com/optest/index.php?route=common/home

can some one let me know what could be the reason

Comment: If the same code works fine on cart page, then you might have selector issue on the home page. Give unique selector to your fields so that other script will not conflict with it.

Comment: how to do that ? or let me try with product id

Comment: Quantity is not passing when you click add to cart button. Your script is just changing the text of quantity box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass quantity parameter in `cart.add()` function.

For ex :-
    `<button type="button" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>',$(this).parent().parent().find('input:first').val());"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span></button>`

Change corresponding values as per your requirements.

Actual function accepts two parameters 
`cart.add(product id, quantity);`

Answer (score 0):

For add quantity selector you need to edit cart.add function that are find in common.js, you can make your own function and add one more parameter in function like :

> cart.add('product id','quantity')

or you can find this extension [more about here](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=25282&filter_search=add%20plus%20minus)