# If Condition - minimum amount undefined variable error in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

Minimum amount text shows perfectly until it cross the amount of 75 after that its show undefined variable 
for an eg. I added a $20 product, 2 times so my cart is $40 so my conditions shows "Minimum Order Value $75 to proceed Check out"
again now I have added another product of 10 dollars, now my cart is $50
so my conditions shows "Minimum Order Value $75 to proceed Check out" text
but the same once my cart crosses $75 its shows the below error

**error**

```
Notice: Undefined variable: error_min_amount in C:\xampp\htdocs\optest\catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\product.tpl on line 176
```

product.tpl view code

```
 <?php if ($error_min_amount) { ?>
                         <div class="alert alert-danger"> <?php echo $error_min_amount; ?></div>
  <?php } ?>
```

product.php controller code

```
        //msg minimum value
              $subtotal = '75';
      // echo $subtotal .'<br />';

              $data['cyc'] = $this->currency->format($subtotal, $this->session->data['currency'], false, false);

      //echo $data['cyc'] .'<br />';

              if($this->session->data['currency'] == 'EUR') : 
      if($this->cart->getSubtotal() < $data['cyc']) :

        $data['error_min_amount'] = 'Minimum Order Value €'.$data['cyc'].' to proceed Check out';


        endif;
        elseif($this->session->data['currency'] == 'USD') :
        if($this->cart->getSubtotal() < $data['cyc']) :
        $data['error_min_amount'] = 'Minimum Order Value $'.$data['cyc'].' to proceed Check out';


        endif; 
        elseif($this->session->data['currency'] == 'GBP') :
        if($this->cart->getSubtotal() < $data['cyc']) :
        $data['error_min_amount'] = 'Minimum Order Value £'.$data['cyc'] .' to proceed Check out';
     endif; 

endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `$data['error_min_amount'] = false;` after `$subtotal = '75';`. That's It.

Comment: can you also check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998210/number-of-quantity-to-is-not-working-in-opencart :) if you can help it will be great for me

Comment: Does this answer help you?